# How would I use Takeown to take ownership of all folders on one drive?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a hard drive which I need to recover specific files from but all the folders in the K:\ drive are denying me access even though I took owner ship of the full drive I.E

> C:\Windows\System32>takeown /F K:\
>   This granted me access to the drive and see the folders but I can not access any of the folders after that.

Is there a way in which I can use Takeown to apply ownership to every directory on the drive>

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### Is there a way in which I can use `takeown` to apply ownership to every directory on the drive?

This can be done in two different ways, using `takeown` or `icacls`.

---

#### Take Ownership of an Object using `takeown` Command

This command will take ownership of the folder or drive, and **all files and subfolders** in the folder or drive.

Open an elevated command prompt (administrator).

To grant ownership to administrators group:

```
takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /A /R /D Y
```

---

#### To Take Ownership of a Folder or Drive and All Contents using `icacls` Command

Open an elevated command prompt (administrator).

To set administrators group as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [icacls](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) - Change file and folder permissions - display or modify Access Control Lists (ACLs) for files and folders.
- [takeown](http://ss64.com/nt/takeown.html) - Take ownership of a file (Windows 2003/7/2008).

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to do it from a system level prompt. Running from a cmd.exe as Administrator was not enough. To do that, I first had to run `psexec -i -s cmd.exe` from an Administrator command prompt, then run the commands from this answer.

Comment: Windows tells me "'psexec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.".

Comment: @NarftheMouse [PsExec - Windows Sysinternals | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add a /R on your command to recurse throughout the subfolders and files...

Comment: Remembering also that the NTFS permissions also come in to affect once you are the owner.. If the NTFS permissions does not allow access to the creator/owner then it will make no difference being the owner...

Comment: yes thank you for this I just this minute found it out haha