# SD card has 26gb large "file"

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, filesystems, disk-space, sd-card

[Windirstat](https://windirstat.net/) shows a large unknown something of 26gb!
[image]

I have a Samsung 128gb microsd in win10 oct update. I cannot see it in explorer. So I tried to run Ubuntu (from win store) and [mounted the sd](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/18/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/).

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/d
$ sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d
```

But `ls -al` does not list it.
Windows says I have 5.8gb free space left. Windirstat confirms that. If I add up all the dir sizes I do get 119.7gb just like Win10 says. However there seems to be something of 26 gb and I want that space back... Have no clue anymore.
I found this [similar issue](https://superuser.com/questions/964820/windirstat-shows-244gb-unknown-space-on-external-drive) and tried TreeSize Free, but it does not even list the 26 gb "file"

p.s. '<Onbekend>' is Dutch for '<Unknown>'

p.p.s. the filesystem is exfat

Just tried to run `docker system df`  and everything is 0. even when I have a `MobyLinuxVM.vhdx` of 2gb on my C:/

[image]

I think that I have found it. There is a huge difference between the size and allocated size for my code folder. which has archives and git repo's. that difference is shown in windirstat as some unknown thing, when treesizefree just has these two columns with size and allocated size.

Comment: I guess it could be space used in the [wear-levelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) process.

Comment: So Windows and TreeSizeFree do not show it and Windirstat does. But I cannot find a reference that exfat has wear level support or a samsung micro Sd has support for it...

Comment: Again, only guessing, but the file system has no need to know about wear levelling. It may be possible to ask the drive about it in other ways, but not through the file system. If you read the [no wear levelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling#No_wear_leveling) section in the article I linked to, you would see that it is almost certain that the drive has it. Remember that there are electronics inside the SD card which translate the software instructions into what actually happens in the circuitry.