# Windows shows 150GB less than Chkdsk

Tags: disk-space, chkdsk, windirstat

Windows is reporting 199GB free when CHKDSK reports ~350GB free. The drive in question is a 1TB SSD that was my former Windows drive. I have run disk check and checked for shadows. How can I reclaim that disk space?

WinDirSat and TreeSize

[image: WinDirSat and TreeSize]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

WizTree:

[image: WizTree]

CHKDSK report:

[image: CHKDSK Report]

Comment: What exactly is your question?  It's most likely the Volume Shadow Copy disk usage.  Which is the reason it shows up as "unknown".  You can [edit] your question to provide the necessary clarification.  How WinDirStat and TreeSizeFree work are different.  TreeSizeFree was likely programmed to NOT display anything about the Volume Shadow Copy content.  WinDirStat isn't exactly modern software. [WizTree](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows) is what I recomend.

Comment: I'm asking how to get rid of it. I ran 'vssadmin list shadows' and there weren't any on that drive

Comment: if it was your previous windows disk it might be the hiberfile and page file leftovers. enable show hidden files and open E:\ in details view and sort by size.

Comment: @twincessna340a - If you are asking how to remove the file, then we need more information to confirm, if the system is an artifact from your previous installation or something you can safely delete.  However, you must also, [edit] your question and clarify what your question actually is.

Comment: When ''show hidden" is enabled the only things shown are what's listed in TreeSize (except the recycle bin and the system volume information). I have already deleted the page file which was hidden from the "show hidden" and only found using TreeSize. I have yet to see any references to the hiberfile....I have never had an option to hibernate my computer on the shutdown menu anyway.

Comment: @Ramhound I have also added the WizTree capture to the question.

Comment: @twincessna340a - [You ran all programs as an Administrator, I presume?](https://superuser.com/questions/964820/windirstat-shows-244gb-unknown-space-on-external-drive?rq=1).  Based on the numerous answers to that question I would assume that’s NOT the case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WinDirStat shows 244GB unknown space on external drive](https://superuser.com/questions/964820/windirstat-shows-244gb-unknown-space-on-external-drive)

Comment: @Ramhound yes, all programs were run as an administrator. I even have them set to

Comment: @Ramhound I have posted the CHKDSK report. It reports 350GB free....

Comment: Still a permission problem.  If you don’t intend to boot from the disk just delete the files

Comment: Delete what files? The folders that are left are to be kept. I could care less what the 3 programs report....Windows is reporting 199GB free. CHKDSK is reporting 350GB free. I have even changed the ownership of everything on that drive to me. Why is Windows disagreeing with itself?