# 19GB of used space on laptop no files for it?

Tags: windows-10

I'm using a HP15
Windows 10
Intel Pentium 2.16GHz
Installed RAM 4.00GB 3.89 usable
In recovery D: 20.5 GB used out of 22.2GB.
However, when I look in storage usage 19.7GB is used under OTHER files. When I look under OTHER files it says, (we couldn't find any folders to show you. What is occupying that much space without files? And how do I do away with whatever it is?

Comment: Try WinDirStat or alternatives.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/965332/1482432

Comment: Before you delete it, google what it is. Possibly a recovery partition