# Windows 11: Find and Grant read Permission for Unreadable files

Tags: permissions, ntfs, windows-11, administrator, windirstat

I'm using WinDirStat to see how my hard drive is being used. I see 9.2 GB marked as `<Unknown>`. I'm assuming these are files which my Windows user can't read. I'm an administrator, and the hard drive in question is not the primary drive, so it doesn't have Windows on it. It's for data only -- pics, videos, games. I don't necessarily want to just "take ownership" of everything. I would like to know which files/folders are unreadable - or at least which folder the unreadable files/folders exist in. Is there a utility that will help me as an Administrator find the files that WinDirStat can't see, and show me some information about them? **And**, is there a utility that, rather than taking ownership, will just grant me read permissions on all files that I can't currently read?

Comment: Try Lock Hunter.  I use this and it is helpful

Comment: try  http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WinDirStat shows 244GB unknown space on external drive](https://superuser.com/questions/964820/windirstat-shows-244gb-unknown-space-on-external-drive)