# Windows 10 Home - cannot access admin only drive as administrator

Tags: windows-10, security, administrator

I upgraded my Windows 7 HOME to Windows 10. I had some user accounts, one an administrator, the other a standard user. I had edited the security so that some drive and folders had no read permission for other users.

Now, Even I cannot see those drives with file explorer, I can only see them with command prompt with elevated privileges even though my account has all access.

I don't want to give access to other users, but I want a way that my admin user can have full rights to those folders and other user no rights at all.

Is that a downgrade of feature from Windows and I would need Windows 10 Pro ?

Comment: [How would I use Takeown to take ownership of all folders on one drive?](http://superuser.com/a/813881)

Comment: As I explained, my 2 users have different access. And taking ownership of all drives will not give access to the other user. So no, that won't do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After some validations, it appears that Microsoft outdone themselve on this matter. ***(sarcasm)***.
Your user must have explicit access, meaning not from the group he is in, but with the exact user he is.
So, by adding your exact user in the listed security tab, UAC will not prompt and you will have access to everything you should.
I'm really annoyed by this. 
And the fact you cannot run the file explorer with administrator privileges.