# How do I wipe the Windows folder from another hard drive?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, administrator

With Windows 10 Anniversary, I got a harddrive from a relative and want to wipe everything on it. I am trying the [Registry edit of Taking Ownership](http://www.tenforums.com/general-support/12525-cant-delete-folder-windows-requires-administrator-permission.html) but 4 folders (servicing, System32, SysWOW64, and winsxs) will have the error in the image below. I went into Properties>Security>Advanced and made my account (which is administrative) the only one in the list with Full Control (some reason it won't let me check Special Permissions) but it still will not delete.

[image: The Error]

Comment: Step 1: Take Ownership of the contents of the Folder.  Step 2: Delete the folder.  Of course there is an easier solution.  **Just format the drive in question.**  Based on the screenshot the user your using, is not, `BUDGETDATA\Alex` you should use that account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I use Takeown to take ownership of all folders on one drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/813878/how-would-i-use-takeown-to-take-ownership-of-all-folders-on-one-drive)

Comment: @DavidPostill From research I have been doing, there are differences between Windows 7 and Windows 10 Anniversary, making the process different. I went through the instructions on the possible duplicate and it didn't work.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow It's the same in Windows 10. See [How to Change Owner of File, Folder, Drive, or Registry Key in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3587-owner-files-folders-change-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: @CamouflagedCow - We are missing some criticial information.  How you take ownership of a folder has not changed since I believe it would be Windows 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ramhound says, if you want to wipe everything from a hard drive, just format it.

`format (drive:) /FS:NTFS` should do the trick.