# No Permission to open files on new computer

Tags: permissions, transfer

i had to give up my work computer so i transferred all files to my WD my Book.  i'm running Windows 10 I can see them on the new computer but can not access them. when i double click a file it says i do not have permission to access this folder.

Comment: What folders. Make sure you are on a private Network Connection.  Make sure you had permission before you transferred. Transferring folders from USERS may require you to take ownership

Comment: See https://www.howtogeek.com/301768/how-to-take-ownership-of-files-and-folders-in-windows/ . Also, are there .lck files present, because the files were open in MS Office? Delete them.

Answer (score -4):

The files may be owned by the account on the old computer,
so your account on the new computer cannot access them fully.

You need to take ownership of the containing folder on the WD.

See the following articles for useful solutions:

- [How would I use Takeown to take ownership of all folders on one drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/813878/how-would-i-use-takeown-to-take-ownership-of-all-folders-on-one-drive)
- [How to Take Ownership of a Folder in Windows 10 Using File Explorer](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer)
- [How to Add Take Ownership to Context Menu in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3841-add-take-ownership-context-menu-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: You might want to add the necessary steps to your answer instead of just adding a link.

Comment: @mashuptwice: This has been repeated countless times and flavors on SU. I have added a link within SU for such an answer.

Comment: You could then flag this question as a duplicate and link to the original question.

Comment: This is only one method among several and not an exact duplicate.

Comment: Useless downvotes.