# Cannot delete a user profile folder in windows explorer

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-explorer

I'm administrator on my machine, but can't delete an user or profile folder. I have tried several options. I have found [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/deleted-user-but-cannot-remove-profile-folder/c41062a2-72ed-4a78-a601-1ae6dc4f947c) page and tried to use the registry. But nothing really works.

Every time when I delete the user profile folder, it asks for permission from the administrator. And then it seems like it will work. But then a message will pop up that you don't have permission. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Make sure the User Account is deleted first before trying to delete the Profile in the USERS folder. Once the Account is deleted, restart, go back and try to delete the folder.

Comment: The User Account was already deleted

Comment: Make another Windows User Account, make it a Member of Administrators, log out, log into the new Account and delete the User Profile that way.

Comment: After doing that it still gives me this message: "You need permission to preform this action. You require permission from S-1-5-2021-xxx to make changes to this folder" And then gives me two buttons `retry` and `cancel`

Comment: You probably need to Repair Windows using the Microsoft Media Creation link.

Comment: Try [taking ownership of the directory](https://superuser.com/questions/813878/how-would-i-use-takeown-to-take-ownership-of-all-folders-on-one-drive/813881#813881)

Comment: Have you tried "the old way"?  Run `systempropertiesadvanced` -> User profiles -> [Settings].  Delete from there.  The new settings all suck.

Comment: As suggested try the take ownership commands.  If this doesn't help, set the necessary permissions - this is often enough to delete specific files/folders in System32 folder for example. Some protected files in SysWOW64 even requires to set the permissions in safe mode or you don't have access at all and sometimes you can only start a deletion process successfully within the console window of the command safe mode boot type.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have already tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Hey @SeñorCMasMas, your solution helped! It's incredible how old option can do such good things! It was done with just one click! I'm so surprised that it works! Thanks man!

Comment: @Bennpoes - You should submit a detailed answer to indicate exactly what worked for you.

Comment: Yes @Bennpoes :)  Glad it helped.  Please write up what worked as an answer and take the points so you can play here.  I don't care about points.  I only care about helping people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

As Señor CMasMas said, I go to the system properties to fix it. First, press Windows key + R and run `systempropertiesadvanced`. Than go to User profiles -> [Settings]. Then a window will pop up. Select the user that you want to delete. After that the user will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where I could not delete a left over user's folder after removing the user, and none of the various solutions found worked in my case.

Finally, I came across [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/721392/63361), and that worked for me.

In a Command prompt (`cmd.exe`) started as Admin:

```
rd /s /q C:\Users\My_Deleted_User
```